# Next js website's reload redirects to homepage on Apache server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, next.js

I have a static Next.js website hosted on Apache server(control panel) at first when I reloaded a page it gave me a 404 error but now when I'm reloading it always goes to the homepage, I tried to include `.htaccess` file on my public folder but it doesn't work; here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

in another project thus `.htaccess` file worked just fine but now its not working; I use NPM build & export &
I don't use any ssr function on my code. I'll be happy if you help me out what did I do wrong this time.

Comment: have you find any solutions? I also stuck at this problem

Comment: @AlanYong no one answered but I tried to host my next js on vercel and not static but for the static part I think we should use this: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-paths, but trust me hosting on vercel and not static saved my life with these kind of error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, I have fixed it by placing the .htaccess file inside root directory with following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
  
</IfModule>
```

maybe you can find more info here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/10522?sort=top

I found others solutions (that don't work for me) such as:

- Generate a exportPathMap on next config
- Set TrailingSlash to true on next config

more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/exportPathMap