# Nextjs Apache .htaccess redirects my app to base url on refresh

Tags: reactjs, apache, .htaccess, next.js

I have a static application in production, and it's hosted on apache server, now everything is working fine except when I go to a single resource (details page), and refresh, the app goes back to the base url.

- https://{base_url}/dashboard/invoices/list/ **(refreshes alright)**
- https://{base_url}/dashboard/invoices/150/ **(goes back to {base_url})**

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

Comment: `(goes back to {base_url})` could you please elaborate more on this one? I mean **from** which url **to** which url its going?

Comment: from (https://{base_url}/dashboard/invoices/list/) to (https://{base_url}/dashboard/invoices/150/)

Comment: Ok your shown htaccess doesn't look like is causing this error. Do you have any other .htacess rules file apart from this in your system?

Comment: No, only this file.

Comment: So when you hit `https://{base_url}/dashboard/invoices/list/` in browser it goes to `https://{base_url}/dashboard/invoices/150/` is it the case?

Comment: the list page (https://{base_url}/dashboard/invoices/list/), I can open details items, let's say entry 150, it goes to (https://{base_url}/dashboard/invoices/150/), it opens normally, but if I click refresh, it goes back to (https://{base_url}/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Next js website's reload redirects to homepage on apache server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71065992/next-js-websites-reload-redirects-to-homepage-on-apache-server)