# Next.js deploy environment router

Tags: next.js, interrupt, cdn

When I run the next build and next export command get a folder out. In this folder, we have some static pages. When I copy out the folder to CDN, and config the router to the homepage. After that, I can visit the site. But when I enter other pages and refresh the browser, the router to the homepage, but the URL is still on the other page. Besides right-click view the source code is still on the homepage. All of these problems didn't come up in dev environment.
I use `isr`. Here is the out file:
[image: Out file]

Here is the problem. The URL is blog but the browser shows the homepage.
[image: Homepage]
I want to know how to config the CDN router to fix the problem and when I right-click the view the source code shows the current page source code.
thank you for any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/75989429/15353979

Comment: I figure out this bug，add nextjs config `module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
}`
CDN can't get /blog but if I change the url /blog.html it works.I think the problem is CDN can't find the blog resouce.